# Using the same button across multiple tabs swing

Tags: java, swing

I am currently trying to write a program that uses multiple tabs to display different characters composed of the same information. I am trying to be able to increase the stats of the character but am unable to use the same button constructor to build the buttons as java does not allow multiple instances of the same button. I have tried encompassing it in an object and adding the object to the array, but that only moves the buttons to the newest sheet.

My question is, what would be the best method to create the necessary buttons and allow them to be used without having to create an arbitrary number of buttons to accomplish this?

I have included the method for initial creation and how I place the buttons:

```
abilPlus = new JButton[8];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 8; counter ++){
        abilPlus[counter] = new JButton("+");
    }

public void placeButtons(){
    abilPlus[0].setEnabled(false);
    gbcSP.gridx = 4;
    gbcSP.gridy = 1;
    gbcSP.gridwidth = 1;
    statPane.add(abilPlus[0], gbcSP);

    // More of the same in the middle...

    abilPlus[7].setEnabled(false);
    gbcSP.gridx = 19;
    gbcSP.gridy = 2;
    gbcSP.ipadx = 0;
    gbcSP.gridwidth = 1;
    statPane.add(abilPlus[7], gbcSP); 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you can't use the same instance of a `Component` in multiple `Container`s, lots of technical reasons why, but we can ignore those for the moment. Instead, you can use a single instance of an `Action` (or multiple instances of the same `Action`) which does the key work which is required. This should then update a model of the stats which generates notifications when it's changed so other "observers" can update there own state when they change

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html). You might also find [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) useful

Comment: I would also consider making a component which encapsulated the functionality you're trying to communalise and simply create an instance of it when you need it

Comment: Thank you for the information. I think Actions may be my best bet.